# reflection - Accessibility of public static classes nested inside package local classes

Tags: java, reflection, inner-classes, class-visibility

In my example I have two packages: `package1` contains class `A` (NOT declared as public) and its nested static class `B` (declared as public):

```
package package1;    
class A {
    public static class B {
        public B() {
        }
    }
    public A() {
    }    
}
```

`package2` contains a `Main` class with a simple main method that tries to reflectively create an instance of class `package1.A$B`:

```
package package2;       
public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class<?> innerClass = Class.forName("package1.A$B");
            Object o = innerClass.newInstance();
            System.out.println(o);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}
```

Surprisingly (at least for me), this piece of code succeeds in doing something otherwise impossible without reflection. Classic `import` statements (like `import package1.A.B;` or `import package1.A.*;`) raise errors arguing that class `A` is not visible. Moreover, there is no need to require special accessibility priviledges to create the instance of `B`. Is it a normal behaviour?

**EDIT**: It works also if I get a reference to the inner class in a different way, like this:

```
Class<?> innerClass = Class.forName("package1.A").getClasses()[0];
```

Comment: How can you create a non-public `A` class? is it part of any other public class?

Comment: Saying "not public" I mean default (package) visibility.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is a absolutely fine. When you write like `package.classname$innerclass`, you can get the static innerclass.

Comment: ok but in this case I was expecting a `java.lang.IllegalAccessException` at construction

Comment: An IllegalAccessException is thrown when an application tries to reflectively create an instance (other than an array), set or get a field, or invoke a method, but the currently executing method does not have access to the definition of the specified class, field, method or constructor.  Class B is public and static and easily accessible

Comment: ok, but if it's legal to access class B because it's public, why is it  impossible to directly import class `package1.A.B`?

Comment: Here comes, the concept of ClassLoaders. Let me try to explain : See when you do import class package1.A.B, it tries to search for that class at compile time , but the class is not visible and gives the error. But when you do Class.forName - it goes to the class loader with String value(which is a fully qualified class name). and looks for that class in classloader which it has and therefore successfully returned.